# Shared NTFS logical partition unaccesible from Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, multi-boot, diskpart, logical-drive

I asked this question a while ago but it got lost, so I deleted the previous one and created this new one with updates from the comments.

I just installed Windows 8.1 in a partition of my Lenovo Thinkpad T420 which also has an Ubuntu partition. As usual, GRUB was lost so I entered with a Live CD and recovered it succesfully, being able to boot both OSs.

The issue is that I already had a shared logical NTFS partition and I can't access it from Windows now. I entered Computer Management and the partitions are there but are shown with 100% free space. This is pretty obvious with the Ext4 partitions, since Windows can't access them, but this also happens with the NTFS partition, as shown in the following image.

[image]

I googled about this and ended up using `DISKPART` in order to manually mount my partition, but I got an error that says my partition is not assigned to any volume, and when I list them, no volume is shown for the partitions shown in the previous list in the following image.

[image]

If I run `fdisk -l` on the partition it says it can't be opened.

Answer (score 0):

There are many disk recovery tools.

You can use for example [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/).

It is possible that some partition parameters are not written correctly in header so partition is not recognized properly.

Comment: I will try this and update the post accordingly, thanks a lot!